# Traversing twitter timeline

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, twitter

Using the rest api at twitter, the server only serves a limited amount of tweets. I'm trying retrieve a user history by looping with the max_id which is the suggested method in the api. However, with each call, I get a new xml header, which is throwing a SAX Parser error so that I can't retrieve the max_id. I looked at the java api for Transformer, and OMIT_XML_DECLARATION but I'm not sure where to put it in my code, whether the xml declaration should be removed in the connection, the print method, or when the document is handled. I couldn't figure out the Transformer output... though I've looked at it in depth.

```
public class DataGrabber {

File destFile;
int qcount = 0;

public void getRuserHx() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, InterruptedException, SAXException {
        int downNodes = 0;
        Integer statTot = 10;
        String maxId = null;

        File filename = new File(MyIds.hoopoeData + "/" + MyIds.rootUser + "Hx.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc;


            //loop and download based on the id of the last tweet
            while(downNodes < statTot){
             System.out.println("Getting user status history...");
             String filex = MyIds.rootUser + "Hx.xml";
             String https_url = "https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=" + MyIds.rootUser + "&count=300";
             makeConnection(https_url, filex);

             //validate the xml before you parse
             doc = builder.parse(filename); 
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

             //set up for the loop           
             downNodes = HooUtil.nodeCount(filename, "status");
             statTot = Integer.parseInt(HooUtil.nodeValue(filename, "user", "statuses_count", 0));

             Long loopMax = (Long.valueOf(HooUtil.nodeValue(filename, "status", "id", downNodes - 1)) - 1);
             maxId = loopMax.toString();
             https_url = "https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=" + MyIds.rootUser + "&count=300&max_id=" + maxId;
             Thread.sleep(4000);
             qcount ++;
            }


        System.out.println("Finished downloading user status history.");

  }

    //connect with the input query
public void makeConnection(String https_url, String filex){
    URL url;
    try {     
         url = new URL(https_url);
         HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();          
         //dump all the content into an xml file
         print_content(con, filex);

    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    //the print method for the xml file
private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con, String filex){

    if(con!=null){

        try {           
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

              destFile = new File("/" + filex);
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(MyIds.hoopoeData + destFile, true)); 
              String input;
              while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
              out.println(input);
        }

           out.flush();
           out.close();
           br.close();  

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Umm, use JSON? It is much simpler to parse.

Comment: I'm not parsing into text. I'm reformatting into csv and pushing to a db. JSON is only easier if you know it, which I don't, but there would still be a declaration, no?